# Invocar métodos con variables redundantes desde múltiples puntos de una aplicación

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, buenas-prácticas, eficiencia

Tengo una función que genera ficheros EXCEL con los siguientes parámetros de entrada:

```
    private Map<String, Object> writeExcel(List<Map> registros,
                                           int modeloExcel, String nombreFichero, String nombreHoja) {}
```

Este método es un método genérico que estoy montando al que invocare desde distintos puntos de la aplicación, de los cuales el parámetro "nombreHoja" solo se utiliza en una serie de casos específicos.

Por lo que tengo entendido, dado que nombreHoja es un campo que no tengo que informar siempre debería crear un método que hiciera lo siguiente:

```
private Map<String, Object> writeExcel(List<Map> registros, int i, String nombreFichero) {
    return writeExcel(listaTarifas, i, nombreFichero, "");
}
```

De modo que invocase mi método principal desde este punto si no tengo el parámetro "nombreHoja".

Alguien puede explicarme porque esto es una buena práctica (si lo es) y pasarme un poco de información adicional, o explicarme si debería en lugar de hacer esto llamar al método con un "" directamente.

EDIT: Adjunto la función:

```
 /**
 * @param registros
 * @param modeloExcel
 * @return
 */
private Map<String, Object> writeExcel(List<Map> registros, int modeloExcel, String nombreFichero, String nombreHoja) {
    Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        Workbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook();
        switch (modeloExcel) {
            case 1:
                Sheet hojaTarifas = libro.createSheet(Constants.HOJA1); 
                Row primeraFila = hojaTarifas.createRow(0);
                generarExcelTarifasGrupo(registros, hojaTarifas, primeraFila, libro); //Columnas y datos específicos
                break;
            case 2:
                Sheet hojaRecargo = libro.createSheet(nombreHoja); //nombre dinamico que puede varias
                Row primeraFilaRecargo = hojaRecargo.createRow(0);
                generarExcelRecargoDescuentos(registros, hojaRecargo, primeraFilaRecargo, libro, nombreHoja); //Columnas y datos específicos
                break;
            case 3:
                //Por añadir Hoja con nombre dinamico
                break;
            case 4: 
                //Por añadir Hoja con nombre estático
                break;
            default:
                //Por controlar
                break;
        }
        response.put("file_name", nombreFichero);
        libro.write(outputStream);
        libro.close();
        log.info("DATOS EXPORTADOS CORRECTAMENTE");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        log.error("### SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR EXPORTANDO LOS DATOS A FORMATO XLSX");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("### SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR EXPORTANDO LOS DATOS A FORMATO XLSX");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    response.put("content", outputStream.toByteArray());
    response.put("file_ext", "xlsx");
    response.put("typeFile", "application/xlsx");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Grismak, es imposible dar una respuesta acertada sin un poco de contecto, por ejemplo, a mi se me ocurre que para no escribir métodos redundantes, es válido pasar el argumento **hombreHoja** como "", pero... lo puedes manejar dentro del método?, no afecta ese retorno al funcionamiento de lo que sea que lo recibe?, si nos muestras un poco más de tu código, recibiras una mejor ayuda. Puedes hacerte una pasada por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para saber mejor como funciona el sitio, y así evitar votos negativos.

Comment: @MarcePuente He añadido la función. Basicamente es un generador de excel genérico que dentro tendra un switch con distintos modelos de columnas (4 en total) . Los datos vendrán en el List<Map> de registro La clave es que dos de los excel necesitan que los nombres de hoja sean variables. El método aun esta creciendo por eso el JAVADOC no esta actualizado

Comment: La ventaja es que tú controlas el valor predeterminado, que bien podría ser `""` o `null` o `"N/A"` y de alguna manera identificarlo y proceder en consecuencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar un poco el tema, he dado con una respuesta que me ha gustado y lo aclara bastante, la dejo por aquí por si alguien tiene una situación similar ya que es un patrón de diseño

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern/1953567#1953567

Comment: Esto no responde realmente tu pregunta. Tu caso -y su código- están muy lejos de ese patrón de diseño.